Bypass the Android 8.1.0 Setup and entering the settings
I have a tablet which cannot go past the Android setup, once I complete the steps it says that the app "Android Setup" closed. I need a way to bypass this setup so I can open the Settings menu and unlock the bootloader so that I can install LineageOS.
Trying opening the web browser via the google terms of service button crashes the tablet.

An app like the setup process that crashes the whole system is rather uncommon. Have you tried it while the tablet is connected to a charger? May be it is just a weak battery.

Yea, nothing changed. :(

I don't see a way to bypass, thus the only way would be to not run into the problem that crashes the system. AFAIR Android starts with cellular and Wifi enabled after a factory reset. Try to set-up the tablet off-line, may be in a cellar where there is no Wifi reception.  BTW: Which tablet model is affected? May be this is a known problem of the tablet model?
